In Spring Boot, thymeleaf-based documents cannot be redirected
After performing the results forwarded by the ajax request, you are trying to redirect the page.
First, the ajax code.
 fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(message => {
          console.log(message); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MainBannerController {


   @GetMapping("/")
    public String getAllMainBanners(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("mainBanners", mainBannerService.findMainBanners());
        return "../index/index";
    }

   @PostMapping("/upload")
   public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

     try {
        // ... 
        return "redirect:/";
     } catch(IOException e){
        // ...
     }

   }
}

It was performed normally before the return from the controller.
What I expected was that if I did return
"redirect:/";

if I did,
@GetMapping ("/")

would be called and
return "../index/index";

would be returned.
What I added is
Instead of @PostMapping("/upload"), @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.POST) was used.
Return value return "redirect:/"; Instead return "redirect: ../index/index";
I tried it, but it doesn't work as I wanted.
Currently, the ../index/index source code is displayed in Chrome's console window.
../index/index.html is composed of Thymeleaf.

You are using ajax hence you need to handle the response yourself. A redirect is happening but not in the browser because it isn't the browser that is handling the request/response but your javascript call.
